# How do I return specific http status codes from a remote method in loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I would like to know if there is a way to returns a specific HTTP status code from within a remote method.

I can see that there is a callback function which we can pass an error object, but how do we define the HTTP status code?

Comment: which technology do you use?

Comment: if loopback is what we are talking about, here's a response by its authors: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/loopbackjs/oK2g5A_h6vI/VNTD3_GDMQkJ

Answer (score 25):

If you wish to use an HTTP status code to notify of an error, you can pass an error in the remote methods callback method:

```js
var error = new Error("New password and confirmation do not match");
error.status = 400;
return cb(error);
```

You can find more information about the error object here: [Error object](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Error+object)

If you wish to just alter the HTTP response status without using an error, you can use one of the two methods defined by either #danielrvt or #superkhau. To obtain the reference to the request object mentioned by #superkhau, in your method registration you can define an additional argument that will be passed to your remote method. See [HTTP mapping of input arguments](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods#Remotemethods-HTTPmappingofinputarguments)

Comment: Doesn't this return an entire stack trace though?  If you wanted to return `{ status: 404, message: 'Not found'}` is there a better approach?

Answer (score 4):

Lets assume that you have a CoffeShop Model and you want to send status 404 if the item is not in your db.

```
CoffeeShop.getName = function(req, res, cb) {
    var shopId = req.query.id;
    CoffeeShop.findById(shopId, function(err, instance) {
      if (instance && instance.name){
        var response = instance.name;
        cb(null, response);
      }
      else {
        res.status(404);
        cb(null);
      }
    });
  }

CoffeeShop.remoteMethod(
    'getName',
    {
      http: { path: '/getname', verb: 'get' },
      accepts: [{arg: 'req', type: 'object', http: { source: 'req' }},
                { arg: 'res', type: 'object', http: { source: 'res' }}],
      returns: { arg: 'name', type: 'string' }
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 4):

When using an `async` remote method function, you need to let the `async` function throw any encountered errors, rather than trying to catch them and call `return`. By calling `return` you're telling LoopBack that it should respond as if it were successful.

Here's an example working structure.

```
AdminDashboard.login = async(body) => {
  let username = body.username
  let password = body.password
  await isDomainAdmin(username, password)
}
```

```
AdminDashboard.remoteMethod(
  'login',
  {
    http: {path: '/login', verb: 'put'},
    consumes: ['application/json'],
    produces: ['application/json'],
    accepts: [
      {arg: 'body', type: 'Credentials', http: {source: 'body'}}
    ]
  }
)
```

Just make sure that any internal functions you call like `isDomainAdmin` are also either throwing their errors directly, or that you catch them and convert them to an error object like this:

```
{
  statusCode: 401,
  message: 'Unauthorized'
}
```

Where `err.statusCode` is the HTTP status code you want LoopBack to return.

Answer (score 3):

You can return any status code just like you would in ExpressJS.

```
...
res.status(400).send('Bad Request');
...
```

See http://expressjs.com/api.html

Comment: I understand that; but how do you get an instance of express response?

Comment: Depends what part of the lifecycle you're in. In some places, you have access to ctx, in which case you can do `ctx.req`. There are also major discussions around getCurrentContext: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1676.

Comment: Why is it downvoted? It works and it's not deprecated api, http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status

Comment: How to get a reference of res ?

Answer (score 2):

In your remote method registration:

```
YourModel.remoteMethod('yourMethod', {
    accepts: [
      {arg: 'res', type: 'object', http:{source: 'res'}}
    ],
    ...
    returns: {root: true, type: 'string'},
    http: {path: '/:id/data', verb: 'get'}
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to modify response status, just do:

```
ctx.res.status(400);
return cb(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Loopback 4 there is an `HttpErrors` class for this. Here are just a few:

```
// Throw a 400 error
throw new HttpErrors.BadRequest("Invalid request");

// Throw a 403 error
throw new HttpErrors.Forbidden("You don't have permission to do this");

// Throw a 404 error
throw new HttpErrors.NotFound("The data was not found")
```

You can also inject the `Response` object in the controller's constructor and explicitly call it:

```
// As a constructor argument
@inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) private res: Response

// In your method
this.res.status(400).send("Invalid request");
```